# HTTP example for I-Phone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am searching for HTTP example for I-phone 3.0. i am doing SyncMl application  , which is uses http based protocol to syncronise two databases (ie client and server ) Using POST and GET.So i will be sending data to server using POST and reading data using GET.If anybody has sample code or any hint what type framework would be used ??

Comment: What's an "HTTP example"?  Are you looking to download files? Upload files? Respond to HTTP requests?  All of these use HTTP and have examples.  Please be more specific.

Comment: i am doing SyncMl application  , which is uses http based protocol to syncronise two databases (ie client and server ) Using POST and GET.So i will be sending data to server using POST and reading data using GET.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to assume you are interested in implementing some plain old HTTP client code.  Requesting a web page etc.

I use NSURL to do my HTTP requests.  It is pretty straightforward.  You can read all about it on the [NSURL Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but here is a snippet of sample code:

```
// set up your request
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60];

// create your connection with your request and a delegate (in this case 
// the object making the request)
_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

You just need to implement some delegate methods to handle the data responses

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Answer (score 3):

ASIHTTPRequest is a great framework for HTTP Requests.

From the [ASIHTTPRequest site](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/):

> ASIHTTPRequest is an easy to use wrapper around the CFNetwork API that makes some of the more tedious aspects of communicating with web servers easier. It is written in Objective-C and works in both Mac OS X and iPhone applications.
>   It is suitable performing basic HTTP requests and interacting with REST-based services (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE). The included ASIFormDataRequest subclass makes it easy to submit POST data and files using multipart/form-data.

There is also a [Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest). The code is [hosted on github](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree).